# Is there a way to exclude from the Search results any page which is linked to a depreciated term

Tags: 2013, search, search-results, managed-metadata, term-store

I have the following :-

- I am working on a SharePoint 2013 server. and I have an enterprise wiki site collection.
- Each wiki page is linked to a managed metadata term store through a site column named `WikiCategory`.
- And each wiki page can be linked to multiple terms through the `WikiCategory` site column
- each wiki page have a “Custom Status” site column with 2 values; active (default) & Expired.

Now I am trying to achieve the following:-

1. To exclude from the search any wiki page which is linked to a single term and this term is deprecated ..
2. To exclude from the search any wiki page which have its “Custom Status” = `Expired` regardless if its term is depreciated or not.

Now I know that i can exclude wiki pages based on their WikiCategory value as follow:-

`Central Administration` >> `Managed Services` >> `Search Service` >> `Result Sources`>>`open the Query builder` >> Add the following `WikiCategory <> “123”`. Which will exclude all the wiki pages linked to a term named 123. But I do not want to follow this approach… What I am trying to achieve is to specify to exclude all the wiki pages linked to a single term and this single term is deprecated (deprecating a term can be done from the term store management by right clicking on the term and click on deprecate term). But if a wiki page is linked to let say two WikiCategories and one term is deprecated while the other is not , then I need to keep showing the wiki page inside the search.

So can anyone advice how I can achieve this ? mainly to exclude wiki pages which have their custom status = expired OR  they are linked to a single depreciated term ?

Thanks in advance for any help ?

Thanks

Comment: You might need to go the (JavaScript) DisplayTemplate route and process all SearchResults yourself before displaying them

Comment: @DannyEngelmanMPW why is not there a way to know if a term is depreciated inside the Search Service level ?

Comment: You have a very specific requirement: *"and one term is deprecated while the other is not "* This use case just does not apply to the majority of the users of this tool, so the tool was never adapted to do it. For the very same reason  your blender can process peeled walnuts and not un-peeled walnuts. FYI for your requirement DisplayTemplates are **the** way to extend the tool.

Comment: @DannyEngelmanMPW but sharepoint is a  bit tricky on how the search results work ,, now let say i write this inside the Search Results query WikiCategory <> “123” then if we have a wiki page linked to 2 terms  (123 & 456) and one of the terms is 123 then the above exclusion query will bypassed since  since "123"+"456" does not equal 123 ... but if i say not contain as -WikiCategory:"123" then if there is a wiki page with 2 terms (123 & 456)  then the not contain will be satisfied...

Comment: @DannyEngelmanMPW second point ,, can you adivce on this approach (a bit like a workaround) ... Can I write a powershell script which run each hour. where the powershell script will check the term store for any depreciated terms and will get the related wiki pages which are linked to a single depreciated term. after that for these wiki pages which are linked to a single depreciated terms , the powershell script will set the wiki pages expiry status to be "Yes".. and as a final step  i will modify the search service Query to exclude any wikipage with expiry status = Yes.. what do you think ?

Comment: Powershell is making it way too complex. Take an existing DisplayTemplate and filter out the results you do not want. Simple JavaScript: https://blog.metrostarsystems.com/2015/09/25/sharepoint-2013-business-connectivity-services-create-a-display-template-for-a-result-source-or-result-type-bonus-part-of-3/

Comment: @DannyEngelmanMPW i did not use DisplayTemplete for search before... but as i know that display template allow me to modify the defualt search template ,, you mention "filter out the results you do not want" so I still  need to exclude from the Search result the wiki pages which are linked to a single depreciated term or have its expiry status = expired... so i not sure how i can exclude from the DisplayTemplete the wiki pages which i do not want to be shown ??